# String out of bounds,

Tags: java, string, indexing

This program is to use the keyboard keys to play notes. I get a different string index out of range for each key I press, ranging from 49 for the 1 to 109 for the m. but I always get this error message. I am new to Java, and any help would be appreciated since I've checked a bunch of forums and haven't found the answer to quite this kind of problem.

The exception is thrown at this line:

```
nextnote = keyboard.charAt(key);
```

This is my code:

```
public class GuitarHero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //make array for strings
        double[] notes = new double[37];
        GuitarString[] strings = new GuitarString[37];
        int nextnote;
        int firstnote=0;
        double NOTE = 440.0;
        String keyboard ="1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
        //for loop to set notes
        for(int i=0;i<37;i++){
            double concert = 440.0* Math.pow(2, (i-24)/12.0);
            notes[i] = concert;
            for(int j=0;j<37;j++){
                strings[j] = new GuitarString(concert);
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            // check if the user has typed a key; if so, process it
            if (StdDraw.hasNextKeyTyped()) {
                char key = StdDraw.nextKeyTyped();
                //charAt gets index of character in string 
                nextnote = keyboard.charAt(key);
                //make sure value is within string
                if(nextnote>=0 && nextnote<37){
                    // pluck string and compute the superposition of samples
                strings[nextnote].pluck();
                    double sample = strings[firstnote].sample() 
                          +strings[nextnote].sample();
                    StdAudio.play(sample);
                    // advance the simulation of each guitar string by one step   
                    strings[nextnote].tic();
                    firstnote=nextnote;
                }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of key when that is called? There are 37 characters in the String `keyboard`, the characters occupy indices 0-36. So if key is > than 36 or < 0 then you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call [`String#indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29), which will give you the index of the character. [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns the character at the given index.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29%20%22String#indexOf) method

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character

and not the [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1.    The first char value of the sequence is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:
`StdDraw.nextKeyTyped();` documentation says:

> What is the next key that was typed by the user? This method returns a
>   Unicode character corresponding to the key typed (such as 'a' or 'A').
>   It cannot identify action keys (such as F1 and arrow keys) or modifier
>   keys (such as control).

`key` is a character not an index at this line. Do the following instead:

```
int charIndexInKeyboard = keyboard.indexOf(key);
if(charIndexInKeyboard == -1) // char not recognized
nextnote = keyboard.charAt(charIndexInKeyboard );
```

`nextnote` should now contain the character you want.

**EDIT:** Here is how your while loop should look like now

```
while (true) {
    // check if the user has typed a key; if so, process it
    if (StdDraw.hasNextKeyTyped()) {
        char key = StdDraw.nextKeyTyped();
        int charIndexInKeyboard = keyboard.indexOf(key);
        if(charIndexInKeyboard == -1){
            // Not recognized, just continue to next
            continue;
        }
        nextnote = keyboard.charAt(charIndexInKeyboard);
        // pluck string and compute the superposition of samples
        strings[nextnote].pluck();
        double sample = strings[firstnote].sample()
        +strings[nextnote].sample();
        StdAudio.play(sample);
        // advance the simulation of each guitar string by one step
        strings[nextnote].tic();
        firstnote=nextnote;
    }
}
```

Comment: @bitva Glad it worked. For future reference and to help your fellow member spot the right answer, please accept this post as an answer if it worked for you :)